# AjaxRequest.get( ) not accepting text/Html from Response.Write() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, response.write

i am using `AjaxRequest.Get()` method from [AjaxRequest](http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/request/source.php).
following is the inline javascript in `analysis.aspx`

```
 function getAnalysis(type) {            
        var innerHtml;      
        AjaxRequest.get(
            {
                'url': 'getAnalysis.aspx?type=' + type
                , 'onSuccess': function (req) { innerHtml = req.responseText; }
            }
        );
        document.getElementById("div_analysis").innerHTML = innerHtml;
    }
```

when `getAnalysis(type)` is called in `analysis.aspx` everything goes fine - ajax request is properly submitted and response is send properly. But at the end value of `innerHTML` remains undefined.

Following is the code of `getAnalysis.aspx` -

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(type == "somwthing") str = load();    
    Response.Clear();     
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";              
    Response.Write(str);      
    Response.End();     
 }
```

When i debugged javascript using google chrome, i found that value of `innerHMTL` is undefined, although everything went fine.
So i dont understand why AjaxRequest class is not accepting text output from `Reponse.Write()`.

P.S. : I have also tried `Response.ContentType = "text/Html";` and `Reponse.Fluch()`.
please guide me thnx in advance.

Comment: what is `load()`'s definition?

Comment: thats dummy, idea is that it is returning a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the div contents in the onsuccess function since it is called asynchronously when the AJAX request completes

```
function getAnalysis(type) {             
        var innerHtml;       
        AjaxRequest.get( 
            { 
                'url': 'getAnalysis.aspx?type=' + type 
                , 'onSuccess': function (req) { document.getElementById("div_analysis").innerHTML = req.responseText; } 
            } 
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: thxn now its working, but there is one more thing, the returned html contains some script tag which are not evaluated ( i guess bcoz of asynchronous call) so how do i get them evaluated.

Comment: You can do it by extracting the script elements (lets say with jQuery) and then doing an eval on them. The best you can do is not include script elements in the HTML you transmit. In most cases there is no reason to do this. Also I believe the problem occurs only when you try to add a script that needs to be executed right away. If you add a script that just declares some function everything should work. And finally if you feel like you really need to do that then ask a separate question since it is a separate problem. Make sure tochoose the title wisely and have an example with no server code